# How to install a Ubuntu 14.04 System on a 128 GB USB

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have been able to do this with an  8GB USB but when trying to do the same on a 128GB USB get various error codes talking about partitions and Mount problems.
Can anyone give me clear instructions how to prepare the USB first as it looks as if it needs a boot partition.    Please go easy on the syntax - I am a beginner but can copy and paste!!!

Comment: My first guess would be that maybe the USB drive has a GPT partition table, instead of an MBR based one. Maybe it helps to create a new partition table on the USB drive - gparted is a powerful GUI tool that allows you to choose what type of partition table it should be. The most compatible one is MBR.

Comment: Can you post the errors you get? Obviously if you can install on one USB drive the process is very similar for another.